# How to do a X or Y in where query mysql for a single variable?

Tags: mysql

The pseudoquery I want to do is the following:

Select * from mytable where (myintvalue = 0 OR 1) AND anothervalue = "SomeValue"

What is the correct syntax for the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `IN` clause

```
Select * from mytable where myvalue IN( 0,1) AND anothervalue = "SomeValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE (myintvalue = 0 OR myintvalue = 1)
/* or */
WHERE myintvalue IN (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where (myintvalue = 0 OR myintvalue = 1) AND anothervalue= 'SomeValue';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM mytable where myintvalue in (0,1) AND anothervalue= 'SomeValue';
```

Should do the trick